# 802.11n router with concurrent b/g/n support?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Any recommendations for wireless 802.11n routers which can concurrently support 802.11n clients at 802.11n speeds, and 802.11g clients at 802.11g speeds?

Is this the norm, or is the router's wireless frequency/bandwidth limited by the slowest client connected to the router?

Also, something that supports 100Mbps uplink natively...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The newest Apple Airport Express can do this, in part because it can run on 5G (for n) and 2.4GHz (g).  It can do N&G on 2.4, but I've been reading mixed reports of this affecting performance.

If you go this route, make sure your wireless n card can do 5GHz - not all of them can.

Comment: That looks like what I need, but it's pretty pricey!
Any other similar products which might be cheaper?

Comment: Here's another option:
http://reviews.cnet.com/routers/linksys-wrt400n-simultaneous-dual/4505-3319_7-33568803.html

Google for "dual band wireless"

Answer (score 1):

The [Linksys 610N](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AZ01EO) is an awesome router. I have it running DD-WRT and it is pretty stable at this point. Still a work in progress, but very solid.

Answer (score 0):

I got a new Netgear WNDR3700 and it has dual bands and dual antennas.  This way you can have b/g/n on one antenna, and a/n on the other.  This router has a very fast 680MHz processor so even dual bands with WPA2-AES aren't an issue.  Very good little machine.